# How to insert a new line char in a CheckBox Description in Java?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, newline, jcheckbox

In my code I am using checkboxes so that you can select multiple options, however these selections are around 100 characters in length and I am wanting to use a smaller, narrow, window. Is there a way to make the checkbox description go across multiple lines? I have tried inserting System.lineSeparator() into the string but this just seems to be skipped over. I would rather not use JLabels/JTextArea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<br/>` where you want to break line.

Comment: That would work for html but I am using it in a Java GUI not a web page.

Comment: You can use HTML in Swing components. See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) for more details.

Comment: I had no idea you could do this, thanks for the tutorial link!

Comment: Yes, it is working with the html. Looks much neater too!